# Simple logic-engine in PHP for limited editorial programming

Tags: javascript, php

I am developing a system that is based on a lot of filters. I get an input, and the input needs to be sanitised. We have already build a large system for sanitation, that has a lot of logic inside it, however we wish to simplify this and make it more agile.

A very simple example: A filter could be, that we get in a feed that contains the words "Boat" "Boaat" "BoAt" and "boat". They should all be mapped to the same entity "boat" in our database.

Now, what we has been looking for, is a way to run very limited javascript, lua, python, anything - inside PHP, without the use of PECL or new binaries for PHP. With this our editors could do something like, very conditional (in JS):

```
var r = VALUE.toLowerCase();
if (r=="boaat")r="boat";
return r;
```

These examples of filters above are -very- simple, and are just to simply what we are looking for.

I would like to keep out of the way of anything that renders down to a simple PHP eval.

So simple question: When wanting a simple logic/scripting-engine inside PHP, that can be executed, with the options to manually insert the "variable environment", what are my options?

Comment: You could convert the casing of both values (either uppercase or lowercase) then do the comparison. That takes care of the different cases. You could look into using soundex or other similar function for pattern-like matching.

Comment: Have you looked at [PHP soundex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.soundex.php)?

Comment: The examples are for exemplification - not for solving.

Answer (score 0):

Why not collect your words in an object and get the normalized word out of it with an access by a lower case word.

```
{
    boat: 'boat',
    boaat: 'boat'
}
```

Access

```
word = words[string.toLowerCase()];
```

Comment: I am trying to move all the conversion logic over to the editor and not the programmer. We already have this kind of solving logic in place, and a huge interface for it. It doesn't scale well, we need more flexibility, as we need the programmer every time a new ad-hoc problem arrises. Again, my example is very simplified, do not read too much into it.